# sequelize how to increment a value from many to many relation

Tags: sequelize.js, increment

I want to increment or decrement quantity value if it exists in orderproduct join table

```
const product = await Product.findByPk('152b12ac-a59e-44f1-b83f-9770e0b8c01e');

let exits =await order.hasProduct(product);
if(exists) { await order.addProduct(product, {through: {quantity : ?? }})}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this way but I think there should be easy way.

```
const [order, isCreated] = await Order.findOrCreate({
  where: { UserId: "e9213d32-a32e-46f5-a085-6b513129fce1", onay: false}});
const product = await  Product.findByPk('0efd4147-f516-431b-8879-2c3b3c38bf22')

const exists = await order.hasProduct(product)

 if(exists) {
    console.log('product exist in order')
    const orderitem = await OrderProducts.findOne({where :{ ProductId: '0efd4147-f516-431b-8879-2c3b3c38bf22'}})
    await orderitem.increment({adet : 1})
    }else {
           await order.addProduct(product)}
```